# Ist Ignoranz absichtlich?

Tags: meaning

Ich bin gerade über [diese Frage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6659/a-question-about-ignorance) auf English.SE gestolpert. Der Autor behauptet, dass auf Deutsch das Substantiv Ignoranz immer impliziert, dass der ignorante Mensch selbst daran schuld ist, etwas nicht zu wissen, weil er sich absichtlich nicht informiert, oder vielleicht weil er vortäuscht, etwas nicht zu wissen.

Das hat mich sehr überrascht. Ich dachte, dass es auch auf Deutsch eine neutrale Bedeutung hat. Es gibt sicher Formulierungen, aus denen klar wird, dass man es erwartet hätte, dass die betreffende Person sich informiert hat, und als Schimpfwort wird es auch ab und zu benutzt. Aber ist das die einzige, oder die primäre Bedeutung? Wird immer vorausgesetzt, dass eine ignorante Person wissend hätte sein müssen?

Comment: Ich würde es wohl nicht als "Absicht" bezeichnen, sondern eher dass die "Wahrheit" dem Ignoranten schlichtweg egal ist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Der Ignorant

Ein Ignorant ist jemand, der sich nicht bemüht, die Wahrheit zu erfahren, sondern sich mit einfachen Erklärungen zufriedengibt, oder sich sogar überhaupt nicht für irgendwelche Erklärungen interessiert.

Es ist also die Geisteshaltung des Ignoranten, die ihn daran hindert, Wissen zu erlangen. Insofern trifft es meiner Meinung nach vollkommen zu, dass den Ignoranten die alleinige Schuld daran trifft, etwas nicht zu wissen.

Ein Ignorant hat kein Interesse daran, die Wahrheit zu erfahren.

Jemand, der nach der Wahrheit sucht, sie aber dennoch nicht findet, ist kein Ignorant. Jemandem, der forscht, recherchiert, zweifelt und nachfragt, aber die Wahrheit trotz seiner Bemühungen nicht findet, so jemand ist kein Ignorant.

### Die Ignoranz

Die Ignoranz ist genau jene Geisteshaltung, die einen Menschen zum Ignoranten macht. Ignoranz ist das in der Persönlichkeit verankerte Desinteresse an der Wahrheit.

### Absicht?

Das Wort »Absicht« würde ich jedoch nicht verwenden. Es ist zwar der Ignorant selbst (und nur er), bei dem die Ursache seines eigenen ignoranten Verhalten liegt, aber eine absichtliche Handlung impliziert meiner Auffassung nach, dass der Ignorant eine Wahl hätte treffen können.

Eine Analogie:
Ein heterosexueller Mann wird sich nicht in einen Mann verlieben. Aber ist es seine Absicht sich für eine Hälfte der Menschheit nicht zu interessieren? Ich glaube, dass es seine Veranlagung ist, die er sich nicht willentlich ausgesucht hat. Und daher hat er keine Möglichkeit, sich auszusuchen, ob er sich in einen Mann verliebt oder nicht. Es wird einfach nicht passieren. Dieses Sich-niemals-in-einen-Mann-verlieben würde ich nicht als absichtliche Handlung beschreiben.

Und nach derselben Argumentation halte ich es nicht für angebracht, das Verhalten eines Ignoranten mit *Absicht* zu erklären. Das würde für mich nämlich bedeuten, dass sich diese Person aussuchen kann, ob sie sich für Tatsachen interessiert oder nicht. Diese Wahl hat aber (wie ich glaube) niemand. Die einen interessieren sich für die Wahrheit, und die anderen tun dies nicht.

Comment: Und im Englischen ist Ignoranz halt keine Haltung, sondern nur Unwissenheit. Diesen Unterschied wollte der Fragesteller beleuchten.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: So habe ich die Frage nicht verstanden. Ich habe verstanden, dass der Fragesteller die Bedeutung des englischen "to ignore" (etwas nicht wissen) als gegeben hinnimmt und nicht weiter hinterfragt. Ich habe verstanden, dass ihm die postulierte Bedeutung des deutschen Wortes "Ignoranz" zweifelhaft erschien, und genau darauf bin ich eingegangen. Zudem hielte ich es für problematisch in einem Deutsch-Forum Mutmaßungen über englische Wörter anzustellen, noch dazu, wo ich meine eigenen Englisch-Kenntnisse nicht für ausreichend halte um diesbezüglich qualifizierte Aussagen zu machen.

Comment: Du hast recht, mein Kommentar hätte besser zu der Frage als zu Deiner Antwort gepasst. Ich habe mich auch unverständlich ausgedrückt, ich meinte den Fragesteller "drüben".

Comment: Volle Zustimmung, insbesondere auch für den Exkurs zur Absicht. Man könnte auch erklären, dass ein Ignoranter Mensch in gewissen Kontexten generell Ignoranz walten lässt aber Absicht eine bewusste Entscheidung in einer Situation bedeuten würde.

Answer (score 4):

Weder noch. Ignoranz impliziert die Möglichkeit, dass jemand absichtlich etwas nicht wissen will oder nicht beachtet. Es ist also weder grundsätzlich absichtlich noch hat das Wort eine neutrale Bedeutung. Denn durch den mitschwingenden Vorwurf der möglichen Absicht hat es eine negative Konnotation.

Answer (score 2):

**Ignoranz** (von *lat.* **ignorantia** = die Unkenntnis) setzt im Gegensatz zur *Dummheit*, *Unkenntnis*, oder *Unwissenheit* im deutschen Sprachgebrauch voraus, dass diese Unwissenheit willentlich, also mit Absicht, herbeigeführt wird.

Diese Absichtlichkeit führt dann auch zu der in aller Regel vorhandenen negativen Bedeutung. Nur selten wird man Ignoranz in einer neutralen Bedeutung verwenden, und auch nur dann, wenn das beharrliche Anstreben einer Unwissenheit im Kontext erwünscht ist.