# Bedeutung von "ignorant"

Tags: meaning, regional

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ignorant) gibt einzig folgende Definition für das Adjektiv **ignorant** an:

> von (tadelnswerter) Unwissenheit zeugend

Es ist mir aber aufgefallen, dass das Wort auch häufig im Sinne von "ignorierend" verwendet wird.

Der Unterschied besteht darin, dass man im ersten Fall nicht über gewisse Informationen verfügt, während im Zweiten, diese einem eigentlich zu Verfügung stünden, sie aber bewusst nicht beachtet.

In gewissen Fällen kann dieser kleine Unterschied eine Aussage fundamental verändern, z.B bei:

> Die Behörden blieben lange Zeit ignorant

Hier könnte die Mitschuld der Behörden von der Bedeutung abhängen.

**Meine Frage ist, ob diese zweite Bedeutung auch korrekt ist und ob es regionale Unterschiede diesbezüglich gibt.**

**EDIT:** Um meine Frage zu verdeutlichen, gebe ich noch Definitionen verwandter Wörter aus dem Duden an:

**ignorieren:**

> absichtlich übersehen, übergehen, nicht beachten

**Ignorant:**

> tadelnswert unwissender Mensch

**Ignoranz:**

> 1. tadelnswerte Unwissenheit, Kenntnislosigkeit in Bezug auf jemanden, etwas
> 2. (selten) das Ignorieren

Die Bedeutung des Verbs unterscheidet sich also von der von "ignorant" und "Ignorant". Weiter bezieht "Ignoranz" beide Bedeutungen mit ein.

Jedoch wird z.B. in diesem [Artikel](https://www.nzz.ch/karriere/studentenleben/haben-sie-eine-minute-liebe-spendensammler-ich-kaufe-euch-eure-gutherzigkeit-nicht-ab-ld.135632) über Spendensammler "ignorant" im Sinne des Nichtbeachtens verwendet:

> **Ignoranz oder Mitgefühl?**
>
> Dabei habe ich natürlich ein schlechtes Gewissen, wenn ich jedes Mal «Nein, Danke»-rufend fluchtartig das Weite suche, sobald sich jemand mit einem Clip-Board in der Hand nähert.
>
> Ich frage mich, ob es darum geht, dass ich nicht **ignorant** wirken will, wie jemand, den die Armut und das Elend dieser Welt kalt lassen? Oder schwingt neben meiner Gereiztheit über den «Ich rette mal die Welt»-Gesichtsausdruck dieser Leute auch ein wenig Mitgefühl mit, weil sie sich stundenlang die Beine in den Bauch stehen und dabei von einem Passanten nach dem anderen abgewiesen werden?

Comment: Related: (https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22501/ist-ignoranz-absichtlich)

Comment: Die verlinkte Frage behandelt vor allem das Nomen "Ignoranz". Bei diesem Wort gibt der Duden beide Bedeutungen an: die Unwissenheit sowohl wie das Nichtbeachten. Beim Verb "ignorieren", nur die Bedeutung im Sinne des Nichtbeachtens. Beim Nomen "Ignorant" sowie beim Adjektiv "ignorant", nur die Unwissenheit.

Comment: In dem Artikel kommt mir das Wort einfach falsch verwendet vor, und ich würde es selbst nicht so verwenden, sondern nur so, wie der Duden es angibt.

Comment: Ich sehe in allen Erklärungen keine Widersprüchlichkeit. Was ist genau das Problem? Ich glaube, es wurde versäumt, die Bedeutung vollumfänglich in allen Wortarten zu erklären.

Comment: "Ignorant" ist übrigens durchaus ein Kandidat für False Friends, wenn's um Deutsch-Englisch-Übersetzungen geht. Meistens ist man gut beraten, wenn man bei der Übersetzung nicht das 'naheliegende' Wort nimmt.

Answer (score 4):

Offenbar kommen **"ignorieren"**, **"ignorant"**, **"Ignorant"** und **"Ignoranz"** alle vom gleichen lateinischen Ursprung. **"ignorare"** hatte sowohl die Bedeutung

> 1. nicht kennen, nicht wissen

als auch die (und da gebe ich Winkelried völlig recht) davon abweichende Bedeutung

> 2. nicht kennen wollen, absichtlich nicht beachten

Ich denke, dass den verschiedenen Ausprägungen dieses Wortstammes über die Zeit verschiedene Bedeutungen mehr oder weniger "zugesprochen" wurden, so wie es heute im Duden steht (will heißen, "ignorieren" wird in neuerer Zeit nur in der zweiten Bedeutung verwendet, während "Ignorant" oder "ignorant" heute nur noch in der ersten Bedeutung verwendet wird).

Freilich sorgt gerade deswegen die Verwendung von **"ignorant"** für einige Verwirrung. Ich würde aber sagen, dass die Verwendung im unteren Satz

> Ich frage mich, ob es darum geht, dass ich nicht **ignorant** wirken will, wie jemand, den die Armut und das Elend dieser Welt kalt lassen?

falsch ist. Oder bestenfalls eine "Adjektivierung" des Verbes "ignorieren" (Die wahre Bedeutung des Adjektives "ignorant" ignorierend... oder der wahren Bedeutung ignorant? ;) )

Regionale Unterschiede diesbezüglich sind mir nicht bekannt.

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke dass Unwissenheit erstmal nicht negativ ist. Unwissenheit an sich wird daher selten als Ignoranz/ ignorant bezeichnet.
Bei Ignoranz gehört mit dazu dass man erwartet dass der Betroffene eigentlich ein besseres Wissen haben sollte. Es beinhaltet also dass jemand sich nicht um das Wissen bemüht hat oder dass er eine Information bewußt unberücksichtigt lässt (ignoriert).

*Beispiele:*
Es ist **ignorant** eine Wortbedeutung bei Stackexchange zu erfragen (und nicht erst im Duden, Wikipedia o.ä. nachzusehen).

Es ist **ignorant** zu behaupten die Erde ist eine Scheibe (obwohl es zb. Satelittenaufnahmen gibt die eindeutig eine Kugel zeigen).

Answer (score -1):

"Er ist ein Ignorant" ist deutlich stärker als "die Behörden blieben ignorant", aber ich würde bei "ignorant" immer eine gewisse Menge an Tadel unterstellen, mal mehr, mal weniger, während das bei "ignorieren(d)" nicht der Fall ist. Ob man über die Information verfügt (oder mit ein wenig Mühe darüber verfügen könnte) ist eigentlich zweitrangig. Auch bei "ignorieren(d)" liegt häufig die Information vor.

Answer (score -1):

Sowohl a, als auch b und c gehen auf Absicht zurück.

B und C sind tadelnswert im Kontrast zu einem "Streber" was erstrebenswert ist. Im sinne von, Lernen ist gut, nicht Lernen ist nicht gut oder tadelnswert.

ignorieren:

> a) absichtlich übersehen, übergehen, nicht beachten Ignorant:
>
> b) tadelnswert unwissender Mensch

Ignoranz:

> c) tadelnswerte Unwissenheit, Kenntnislosigkeit in Bezug auf jemanden,
>   etwas (selten) das Ignorieren