# Wortempfehlung für jemand, der nicht ignorant bleiben will

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

In einer [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22502/22136) von Hubert gibt es so einen Satz;

> Jemand, der nach der Wahrheit sucht, sie aber dennoch nicht findet,
>   ist kein Ignorant. Jemandem, der forscht, recherchiert, zweifelt und
>   nachfragt, aber die Wahrheit trotz seiner Bemühungen nicht findet, so
>   jemand ist kein Ignorant.

aber ich denke er hat den Satz nicht fertig geschrieben. Welches Wort passt am Besten für das Ende dieses Satzes?

> so jemand ist kein Ignorant, sondern ......

Comment: Ein Wahrheitssuchender?

Comment: Rein grammatikalisch und auch semantisch ist das ein fertiger Satz. Die Frage, wie man das Gegenteil von "Ignorant" genau nennt, ist natürlich trotzdem berechtigt. "Wahrheitssuchender" gefällt mir.

Comment: @Annatar "Wahrheitssuchender" gefällt mir auch sehr. Als ich "nicht fertig" geschrieben habe, habe ich gemeint, dass eine Frage im Kopf bleibt, wenn man diesen Satz liest. Man fragt sich selbst (zumindest ich); Ok, das ist kein Ignorant aber was ist das denn?

Comment: @IQV deine Empfehlung gefällt mir sehr, wie ich den vorherigen Kommentar geschrieben habe. Wahrheitssuchender ist jemand, der nach Wahrheit sucht. Wie nennt man eine Person, die nach Information sucht? Ich meine welches Wort wäre allgemeiner (für Wahrheit und Information)?

Comment: @AdInfinitum Das ergibt Sinn. Ein allgemeines Wort, das mir einfällt, wäre "Forscher". Allerdings passt das denke ich nicht genau zu dem, was du suchst, da sich die Wissenssuche da auf ein bestimmtes Fachgebiet beschränken kann. Jemand kann auf seinem Fachgebiet ein Forscher sein, aber in allem anderen trotzdem ein Ignorant.

Comment: @Annatar An Forscher dachte ich auch schon. Aber die finden ja üblicherweise Ergebnisse, wenn vielleicht auch in kleinen Schritten. Aber die Frage war ja nach jemand, der trotz aller Bemühungen nichts findet.

Comment: @guidot wissbegierig, wissendurstig. Sehr gute Empfehlungen. Niemand kann jemanden, der wissendurstig ist, als "ignorant" bezeichnen und eine wissendurstige Person sucht nach der Wahrheit und Information.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Es gibt leider genügend Forscher, die selbst auf ihrem Fachgebiet Ignoranten sind...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Substantive sind vielleicht etwas hölzern, aber passende Adjektive sind:

- *wissbegierig*
- *wissendurstig* oder auch
- *interessiert*.

Comment: Danke sehr für deine Antwort. Ich denke, dass die Antworten sehr gut sind aber "wissendurstig" ist am passendsten denke ich.

Answer (score 4):

Forschen, recherchieren, zweifeln und nachfragen sind die Werkzeuge guter Wissenschaftler, ob nun im akademischen, privaten oder industriellen Umfeld. Deswegen möchte ich den Satz schlicht beenden mit:

> ein Forscher.

Dabei denke ich explizit *nicht* an den Beruf des Forschers sondern schlicht an jemanden, der aus Neugierde einen Sachverhalt verstehen möchte. Man sollte das aber nicht schwarz/weiß betrachten: Beide Forschergruppen haben eine große Überschneidungsfläche.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Wenn du explizit den Misserfolg mit dabei haben möchtest, müsstest du ihn auch explizit (z.B. *erfolgloser Forscher)* erwähnen. Ich bin der Meinung, dass auch in IQVs Antwort das Nichtfinden explizit erwähnt werden muss; dass also der Wahrheitssuchende durchaus auch finden kann. Und im Übrigen bin ich (als Forscher) nicht der Meinung, dass Forscher zwangsläufig Ergebnisse im Sinne der Wahrheit finden müssen – ganz im Gegenteil.

Comment: Ich war auch nicht ganz sicher, ob das Wort "den Misserfolg" beinhaltet soll. Aus dem Grund habe ich meinen ersten Kommentar gelöscht :) Danke schön für deine Antwort. Das macht auf jeden Fall sinn.

Comment: und zusätzlich dazu, du hast Recht. Wissendurstig oder Wahrheitssuchender sagt nicht, dass die Person nicht finden konnte.

Comment: Ich habe alle Antworten "upgevotet" und ich warte, was die Andere denken.

Answer (score 3):

"Jemand, der nach der Wahrheit sucht..." ist im eigentlichen Wortsinn für mich

> ein Wahrheitssuchender.

Für mich hat dieses Wort eine leicht philosophische Nebenbedeutung, die das Suchen aber Nicht-Finden mit sich trägt. Und deshalb trifft es auch alle zu die "forschen, recherchieren, zweifeln und nachfragen".

Answer (score 1):

Jemand, der die Wahrheit sucht, und noch nicht gefunden zu haben glaubt, ist ein **Skeptiker**. Wenn es aus dem Kontext erschließbar ist, würde ich den Wahrheitssuchenden, der auch möglich ist, zum **Suchenden** verkürzen.